# Create a custom login screen for Windows

Tags: windows-7, webcam, login-screen

I have used KeyLemon software for a few days some 2 years ago and I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom Login screen like in KeyLemon for windows 7?

In Keylemon, Windows 7 boots up to the bootscreen with a square window in which live feed from the webcam is being shown ready to recognize the face of the person placed opposite to it.
I have a project in mind and I was wondering if it was possible to do so? Since KeyLemon has already done it, is it possible to create a custom login screen?

I don't think it is wise for me to ask this question by contacting KeyLemon because it 'might' be against company policy and so I am asking here.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289032/custom-windows-authentication-package

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit and navigate to "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background"

Then see if there is a DWORD value called "OEMBackground" and if so set the Hex value to 1. If you do not have OEMBackground then you need to create a new DWORD value key called "OEMBackground" first.

After you are done navigate to "C:\Windows\system32\oobe\" and create a info folder and then inside it create a backgrounds folder and put a JPEG file in there that is less than 256KB and call the file name "backgroundDefault.jpg" , then reboot and your done!

Comment: I did not mean the background wallpaper.  Have you used KeyLemon - Face Recognition